# When do questions get out of the Help and Improvement queue?

Tags: support, help-improvement

While going through the `Help and Improvement` queue I sometimes run into questions that I've seen there before, questions that can no longer be improved and for which the only option to choose is "Skip". Some of them have answers, some of them don't yet have any.

I've also seen questions already edited by someone else, to which I could only respond with "Skip" too.

So, once a question gets into HIQ what criteria gets the question out of the queue? Editing the question gets it out of there, or is there another mechanism involved?